# Online shop shopping cart security

Tags: javascript, html, security, google-chrome-devtools, online-store

I'm programming an online shop with HTML + JavaScript.

I have noticed that I can manipulate the price and amount of items in the shopping cart in the Chrome web browser.

My concern is, that a hacker can manipulate the shopping cart and order the stuff.

How can I make it safe?
Is it safe just to run it on the clint site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit HTML code in browser by Chrome DevTools (or any similar dev tool in other browser) then you are editing this only in your side.

This is because everything that your browser is displaying was received from server (shop). Just because you changed price, does not mean that this prices was changed in server.

Imagine that someone sent you a letter saying "I like You". You took pen and changed it to "I LOVE You". Does this mean that this person now loves you? Unfortunately no... :(

Comment: Is it because the items in the sql database is fix? Or do I have to pramming Something on my server too?

Comment: When you are sending your order to shop, then you are sending just IDs of items + optionally promo code. Then shop (on server side) is making your order with the price they have in database. You are NOT sending request like "I wanna notebook ID 1234 for 499$" but instead it is "I wanna notebook ID 1234" and shop will respond "OK, it will be 499$". Just like in normal shop there are items with barcodes (that will work like ID in online shop), and when you change price on tag, cash register will still charge amount they have in system recognized by barcode.